# ImportError at /accounts/register/ No module named 'honeygen'

Tags: python, django, hash, python-import, importerror

I have no idea how to get rid of this error. I did read about changing the sys.path but I don't understand how to do it because it's not working at all. Can someone help me fix this error?

```
ImportError at /accounts/register/

No module named 'honeygen'
```

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Documents\tryFOUR\src\register\views.py" in register
  13.           user = form.save(commit=False)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Documents\tryFOUR\src\custom_user\forms.py" in save
  50.       user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py" in set_password
  105.         self.password = make_password(raw_password)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\hashers.py" in make_password
  79.     hasher = get_hasher(hasher)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\hashers.py" in get_hasher
  124.         return get_hashers()[0]

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\hashers.py" in get_hashers
  91.         hasher_cls = import_string(hasher_path)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py" in import_string
  20.     module = import_module(module_path)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\importlib\__init__.py" in import_module
  126.     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Documents\tryFOUR\src\honeywordHasher\hashers.py" in <module>
  11. from honeygen import (generate_word, generate_tough_nut, TOUGH_NUT_PROBABILITY,

Exception Type: ImportError at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: No module named 'honeygen'
```

i cannot submit my registration form because i stil have this error . i dont know what to do anymore .

how to properly import this honeygen.py file .

i did try these :

from honeywordHasher.honeygen import honeygen 
from honeywordHasher import honeygen

but it will end up with error as well.

hashers.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import base64
import binascii
import hashlib
import importlib
import string

from django.conf import settings

from honeywordHasher.honeygen import Honeyword 
from honeygen import (generate_word, generate_tough_nut, TOUGH_NUT_PROBABILITY,
                     RANDOM_WORD_PROBABILITY)
from django.core.signals import setting_changed
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import PBKDF2PasswordHasher
from django.utils.crypto import (get_random_string, pbkdf2)
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes, force_str, force_text
from django.utils.module_loading import import_string
from honeywordHasher.models import Sweetwords
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_noop as _
```

Can someone help me?

----EDITED----

it is in here : https://github.com/seanjh/security-hw3-honeywords/blob/master/genword.py . i follow this source code for my honeygen.py . i only add a class name Honeyword

```
.
.
.
class Honeyword(object):
def closed_syllable():
        return choice(CONSONANTS) + choice(VOWELS) + choice(CONSONANTS)
.
.
.
```

hashers.py :

```
def encode(self, password, salt, iterations=None):
        sweetwords = ['road,models,table']
        honeywordtweak = 3
        sweetwords_len = len(sweetwords)
        if iterations is None:
            iterations = self.iterations 
            sweetwords.extend(honeygen.gen(password, base64, ["passfiles.txt"]))
        for i in range(0, 3):
            sweetwords.extend(honeywordtweak.tweak(password[i], 3))
            random.shuffle(sweetwords)

        hashes = []
        for swd in sweetwords:
            hashes.append(self.hash(swd, salt, iterations))
        self.honeydetector.update_index(salt, sweetwords.index(password))
        h = Sweetwords(salt=salt, sweetwords = pickle.dumps(hashes))
        h.save()
        return "%s$%d$%s$%s" %(self.algorithm, iterations, salt, hashes[0])
```

project tree :

```
C:.
├───checkout
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───templates
│   └───__pycache__
├───contact
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───templates
│   └───__pycache__
├───custom_user
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───honeydetector
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───honeywordHasher
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───profiles
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───accounts
│   └───__pycache__
├───register
│   ├───migrations
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───accounts
│   └───__pycache__
├───sqlite
├───tryFOUR
│   └───__pycache__
└───__pycache__
```

Comment: did you install honeygen  from pip?

Comment: honeygen.py is my custom password hasher generator . it cannot be download . it is in the honeywordHasher file as well as hashers.py . same directory @mohammedqudah

Comment: try this and tell me if it helps *from .honeygen import (generate_word, generate_tough_nut, TOUGH_NUT_PROBABILITY,* add a .

Comment: it give me this error : ImportError at /accounts/register/

cannot import name 'generate_word' @mohammedqudah

Comment: show me your honeygen.py file please in the question

Comment: and delete any thing you don't want to show : )

Comment: done @mohammedqudah

Comment: hi, i want to check something so try this and tell me the output <<from .honeygen import * >>

Comment: it give an error : NameError at /accounts/register/

name 'honeygen' is not defined exception location : in my hashers.py file line 50 .  this line : sweetwords.extend(honeygen.gen(password, base64, ["passfiles.txt"])) i posted my def encode codes as well @mohammedqudah

Comment: i think i know your problem but i need on additional information, your project tree

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157425/discussion-between-nuradilla-and-mohammed-qudah).

Comment: Do you have an __init__ file in your honeygen app folder?

Comment: honeygen is not an app . It is a file in my honeywordHasher app and in my honeywordHasher there js __init__.py @rob